# Dynamic display of SQL COUNT according to Month selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i  want to display a total count  of all diabetes patients from the database in a PHP/MYSQL application  when users specify a month from January- December. this specification is done via a dropdown so they can only specify one month only.

```
SELECT COUNT( * )  
FROM (
  SELECT diabetes 
  FROM  registration 
  WHERE diabetes = "yes")
```

what should i add to  this query to  enable it to be dynamic as such to  retrieve count of all diabetes patient for each month according to users selections?
am not very good in PHP, so if i can do this totally with SQL it will be much better for me.

Thanks

Comment: Note: If you have a VARCHAR field for a boolean, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: you're passing the month as a `GET` variable?

Comment: Can we please see some table structure?

Comment: This is a basic question. Can you tell us what you have tried so far in php?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used MySQL for a while, but something like the following should work:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    registration
WHERE   diabetes = "yes"
AND     YEAR(dateColumn) = @Year
AND     MONTH(dateColumn) = @Month
```

where `@Year` and `@Month` are your user-selected values, and `dateColumn` is whatever the date column is named in your `registration` table.